# Managing internal dependencies of a Git project?

Tags: linux, command-line, python, git, open-source

I have a basic question about the management of a Git project with multiple components.
The project I am referring to has a structure as follows:

```
project-name
├── cli
├── api
├── webapp
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── README.md
├── LICENCE
```

My aim is to have a structure that prioritizes maintainability and code reuse. So the core functionalities are all built into a command line interface (cli) in python. I am also building a rest api, and the goal is to make it use the cli in the background to not rewrite the code.

**My first question is:** Is this a good approach? I used many cli based on API (opposite of my approach), such as for AWS. And I also used APIs based on CLIs, such as ffmpeg. So I am not sure if in my case it makes sense to go the way I explained above.

Now to link the api and the cli, I have 2 approaches in mind and I can't know which is the most appropriate.

- Approach A: Call the cli from the api directly using a relative path inside the project. But this would mean that the cli should always be shipped with the api?
- Approach B: Build the cli separately into a python package and publish it on a repository, then use it as a requirement in the API. This looks "cleaner" to me but it means that I wont see the improvements I make in the CLI right away, since I need to build the package again and publish it.

**My second question is :** Which approach is the proper way to reference the cli in the api? (or are there other ways?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: avoid passing calls through your stack using a command syntax. use code references instead. split your CLI app into a library that contains the actual core code, and a CLI instrumentation app that is only worried about being a user interface. that way the library can be used by your CLI or API, without clumsily shelling strings to execute on the cli.

Comment: @FrankThomas, good points! Do you have any recommendation of language / framework to build the "core" part? Knowing that the core component needs to use some other sdks that are only available in go and python

Comment: I haven't done much more than playing with python (I'm a .Net/java/web guy) so I'm not the best authority on these practical design questions, but I'd recommend sticking to a given ecosystem up to the point where there is standards based interface for control (one example being a rest api). in other words, use python-friendly tooling to do the api layer. then you can use whatever you want on the other side of the API.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are numerous problems here:

- The api should not use a CLI. The CLI should use an API.
- While you can put a cli/app/webapp in one repo, this is considered bad design: it's called a *"monorepo"*. Normally you'd want three different repos, where the webapp and CLI both call into the API. This is also better because one Dockerfile hardly make sense -- are you packaging a cli, or a webapp? I would expect there to be a Dockerfile in both the cli and webapp.
- The advantage of using micro-repos over a monorepo, is largely tooling. Tooling will provide much better support for these things.
- Using a microrepo, forces your cli and webapp to be versioned separately from the API. This is always desirable. For example, you can develop two versions of either the web app or the cli, concurrently using two different versions of the API. Pulling in your API from the cli and webapp, work like any other external dependency needed.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply.
- For the CLI vs API and which should use which, is it a rule? Because in my case the functionalities are quite low level (hardware monitoring and virtualization..). It seems to me that a cli is more suitable, and then I can wrap an API around it.
- For the monorepo approach, I did some reseach and I found that a lot of companies are actually moving back to monorepos vs multi-repo. source: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/4c371132ae7321f6d08567eab54a59049e07f246/doc/design/monorepo.md

Comment: No companies are not moving to monorepos, that's a myth. As I said earlier, most tooling doesn't even support it. Yes, there is a rule: the CLI must use the API. The idea of an API is to provide functionality divorced of interface in a single location. It's a library that versioned. It doesn't make sense to write an interface that does not use the API or that implements low-level routines outside of the API: the API implements the functionality.

Comment: ok for the monorepo, but for the cli -> api the dependencies I want to use are only available in python. Does that mean I need to build an API in Python? I was aiming to build it using NodeJS. That's one big reason why I wanted to implement functionalities in a cli then call them using node (api).

Comment: If the dependencies for the API you want to use are only available in Python, then I would either write an API backend in Python using flask or quartz. I would write a CLI that calls into your API. And then you can write your front-end in Angular or React. This is a pretty typical Python workflow.

Comment: fair enough! I never was a Python for web fan but I guess I'll give it a try! Thanks for your reply

Comment: @user3426711 There are other ways to skin the cat, I just don't want you get lost in the rabbit hole.

Comment: I saw that I can build bindings between nodejs and python, but it seems to add a lot of complexity. Ill just go for python to simplify the job :)

Comment: Well, that would be dumb. ;) The most desirable method would be to drop Python for Rust, which is better at everything than Python. Another method would be to tie either low level Rust or C libraries back into Node using FFI. But really, you don't gain much. Node isn't really much better than Python at being a web backend.

Comment: Yeah, I went for python and it seems great so far! thanks for all the input :)